# A question about comparison between orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-rank

$P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an orthogonal projection, if $P^2=P$ and $P^T=P$.
Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ such that $\text{rank}(X)=n$. Now, assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are orthogonal projections such that
$$\text{Im}(P_1)\subseteq\text{span}(X)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\text{rank}(P_1)=m,$$ $$\text{Im}(P_2)\subseteq\text{span}(X)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\text{rank}(P_2)=r,$$  where $m\leq r\leq n$. Which of the following relations is true?
$$\Vert P_1X\Vert_F\leq \Vert P_2X\Vert_F\qquad\text{or}\qquad \Vert P_2X\Vert_F\leq \Vert P_1X\Vert_F,$$
where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\|P_1X\|_F$ and $\|P_2X\|_F$ are numbers, you will always have one of the two inequalities. With the conditions you specified, each could occur, by taking $m=r$ and switching roles.

To make this more concrete, let $n=d=3$, $m=1$, $r=2$. Let
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix},\ \ P_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
P_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\|P_1X\|_F=1,\ \ \|P_2X\|_F=\sqrt{13}. 
$$
If now 
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
P_1=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ 
P_2=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
\|P_1X\|_F=4,\ \ \|P_2X\|_F=\sqrt2. 
$$

Comment: your answer is correct, but I think that one of the aformentioned statements is always false.

Comment: I guess the left inequality is always true and the right inequality is always false, especialy when m<r, however I can't prove it.

Comment: @DavidMayar: No, they arent.

Comment: thank you so much for your great example.

Comment: @Martin Argerami, thank you so much for your convincing answer. It is completely correct.